# Switching from one tab to another in a application

Tags: ios, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have two tabs in the application.
From tab 2 on a particular view i want to switch to **Root View** of the 1st tab.
how do i do this?

In this case simply `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;` wont work as it does not shows root view it shows the view to which user has navigated to before leaving that tab.

I wish to directly switch to first view of the tab 1

Comment: What is main view controller in tab 0? `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that tab1 is a UINavigationController. You will need to popToRootViewController on the first tab

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Depending on how your application is configured, you might create a method on your appdelegate or somewhere in your view hierarchy that hosts both the UITabBarController and the UINavigationController.

If you always want to display the first view of a particular tab when the user returns to it, call the popToRootView from a viewDidDissapear method somewhere. There are lots of ways to do it, but think about the user experience if you do it automatically.